# how can I return 2 values from an Rspec Mock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to mock `Open3.capture2` and I want to return a string and a double for the status. Any idea how to return 2 value?

code under test:

```
stdout, status = Open3.capture2(command)

if status.success?
  puts stdout
else
  puts stdout
  throw "error: could not execute"
end
```

spec:

```
it "throws an error" do
  status = double("status message", :success? => false)
  allow(Open3).to receive(:capture2).and_return("wat?", status)
  ScreenShotWorker.new.perform(url: "www.google.com")
  expect(Open3).to have_received(:capture2)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return it as a array:

```
allow(Open3).to receive(:capture2).and_return(["wat?", status])
```

so you can visualize the code as running this (with a value of '200' for status):

```
stdout, status = ["wat", "200"]
stdout #=> "wat"
status #=> "200"
```

That's how multiple assigment works in ruby - a method can only return a single value, but if it is an array, then you can use multiple assignment.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!